# Can the metal body of a dc motor be used as negative terminal for that motor?

Tags: motor, dc

I need to power a micro DC gearmotor (6V, 0.5A), but due to the position in which it needs to be placed, i can only access the positive terminal (of that motor). It is possible however to connect the negative terminal to the body of the motor (by soldering a wire) prior to placement and then connect another wire to an exposed part of the body, similar to the usage of chassis in automotive circuits.

Is it advisable (or even possible) to do this? Does it affect by any means the normal operation of the motor?

Comment: This can be normally done but the devil is in the detail of the motor and your target installation.

Comment: Electrically this would probably work but soldering to the body of a motor may be very difficult.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without the details of the motor.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.   Sorry i don't know much about the internal structure of the motor;  It's a generic DC gearmotor: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/GW12GA-DC-6V-12V-smallest-Worm-gear-motor-Low-speed-Ultra-mini-gear-box-Reversible-Electric/32837968872.html

Comment: Welcome to the site.  A "generic" motor - especially alibaba supplied - may change its characteristics each time you buy one so what works today might not tomorrow.

Comment: True indeed, but this keeps life from getting boring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminals of small, general-purpose DC motors are almost always going to be isolated from the body, because the direction of rotation is determined by the polarity of the terminals, so you want to be able to select that polarity (and thus the direction of rotation) independently of the electrical/mechanical connection of the mechanical structure of the motor.  If one of the motor terminals were connected to its body, and you needed to mount the motor to a grounded metallic structure, you would need a bipolar power supply to be able to change its direction.  It's much simpler to just leave the metallic body isolated and let the user choose the terminal polarity to suit the application.

Motors that are *not* general purpose are another matter.  If the motor is designed to always run in a specific direction, such as in certain types of pumps, then the polarity of the motor is fixed by the application, and it may be sensible to tie its negative terminal to the housing.  This is especially true in automotive systems, where the frame of the vehicle is often tied to the negative battery terminal and used to carry the return currents for many of the devices in the vehicles.  Electric pumps and such may be constructed this way, however motors that need to be reversible (such as power window motors) will still need to have their terminals isolated.

It would be a simple matter to measure your motor with a multimeter to verify that the terminals are isolated.  Simply check for continuity between each terminal and the case.  Based on the type of motor pictured in the link in your comment, I'm pretty sure you'll find that there is no connection, however if you do, be aware that this does not necessarily mean that you can supply the motor's operating current through the case.  It may be that there is enough of a connection to measure with a meter, but this connection may not be able to carry the full current of the motor without resulting in some damage.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. Indeed the terminals are isolated from the case. What i was trying to say was not to supply the current through the case internally to the terminal, but to use the case more as a connector between two points, for example solder a wire from one terminal to the case and another wire from a different location of the case to the rest of the circuit. If the case is isolated, this shouldn`t be a problem, right? But what about the gearbox? It is most likely connected to the case and the rotor inside.Wont this cause issues if the case carries current?

Comment: Accepting an answer indicates that you are satisfied and consider the issue closed. If you have a question about an answer, you should wait to accept it. There is a possibility that current in the case could damage the gear or bearings. I believe the worst-case would be a case insulated from the mounting and an electrical connection made to the mechanism the shaft is connected to. If you are going to use the case as a conductor you need both the motor windings and the power supply well-connected to the case. You need to visualize the lowest resistance path for the current.

Comment: If the case is isolated, then sure, you can use it as a connection point if you're able to make a reliable connection to it.  However, soldering to the case may result in damage to the motor, as it may raise the temperature enough to soften the glue holding in the magnets, or soften the plastic end caps.  You should also be careful to avoid having current flow through the bearings/bushings and between gears, as this will be likely to cause rapid deterioration of those components.